# How to Display image without internet connection in html page

Tags: html, angular

I want to display an image without internet connection and I also don't want to store the image in cookies. I have already tried with image url in head using link.

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - smiONE(TM) Visa Prepaid Card</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Content/img/icons/error.svg" />
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Content/img/icons/close.svg" />
</head>
```

but image is not dispalyed.

Comment: What do you mean by without internet? You want to embed image in html? you can do that by binary embedding `<img src="data:image/png;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxx...">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as follows

```html
<img src="data:image/false;base64,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" />
```

It uses base64 encode of image and directly stored on src url. It saves the image itself on img tag.

Here is a Online Image Encoder : https://www.base64-image.de/

**Another Option**

If you can use SVG file then also you do not need internet connection. SVG itself hold the data. I think this is the best option because it is scalar vector so you can maintain responsiveness very easily.